# Date type conversion in hive

Tags: hive, impala

I have a date column in String type in 'MM/dd/yyyy' format.
I have to convert this into format 'dd/MM/yyyy' format.

How to achieve this in Hive/Impala ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this,

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date ,'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'dd/MM/yyyy') from date_test;
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: No Sathiyan. I had tried it already but it did not work. It gave output as NULL

Comment: ` select * from date_test;
OK
12/22/2016```

Comment: select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date ,'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'dd/MM/yyyy') fro                                                                                        m date_test;

Comment: it gave me  22/12/2016   let me know if I'm missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need to switch existing substrings you can use `substring`:

`concat_ws('/',substr(date,1,2),substr(date,4,2),substr(date,7,4))`